# Dell 7378 with 7th generation Intel cannot produce sound

Tags: sound, intel, hardware-certification

USB sound card works fine, but I can't make the Intel sound card work at all. The laptop is listed on the [Certified Hardware](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201605-22329/).

$ intel_audio_dump

```
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 13, Permission denied
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
Stack trace:
  #0 [_init+0xc689]
  #1 [_init+0xa2e6]
  #2 [_init+0x1f81]
  #3 [__libc_start_main+0xf0]
  #4 [_init+0x5561]
  #5 [<unknown>+0x5561]
Test (null) failed.
**** DEBUG ****
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 13, Permission denied
(intel_audio_dump:3238) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
****  END  ****
FAIL (-1.000s)
```

Just updated to kernel 4.6. Not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply upgrade your kernel to 4.8.12

You could do this by typing the following in your terminal:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.12/linux-image-4.8.12-040812-generic_4.8.12-040812.201612020431_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.12/linux-headers-4.8.12-040812-generic_4.8.12-040812.201612020431_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.12/linux-headers-4.8.12-040812_4.8.12-040812.201612020431_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
sudo reboot
```